# Find a word from one table in text string of another MS Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

trying to find a key word from one table in another using " SQl like" function
but sure doing it totaly wrong

```
SELECT  

[table1].[id],
[table1].[name],
[table1].[place],
[table2].[key_words]

FROM [table1], [table2]

where [name] like "%" & [key_words] & "%"
```

in MS Access I`ve done it like:

```
select 

[table1].[id],
[table1].[name],
[table1].[place],
[table2].[key_words]

from [table1], [table2]

where [table1].[name] like "*"& [table2].[key_words] &"*";
```

point me  the right direction please

Comment: just replace * with % and & with +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use concat

```
SELECT  
[table1].[id],
[table1].[name],
[table1].[place],
[table2].[key_words]
FROM [table1], [table2]  
where [name] like concat('%',[key_words],'%')
```

Or with sql server concating + sign

```
    where [name] like '%' + [key_words] +'%'
```